# Execute .py programme from HTML button

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I want to execute a python programme whenever the user clicks on any of the buttons from the django submit_line.html page.

I have tried using variations of the following:

```
onclick="python script.py" 



onclick="/usr/bin/python /home/django/project/script.py" 



onclick="python ../../script.py"
```

but I can't get the script to run.

Does anyone know of any solutions to my problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: To execute it how? Instantly? Or by refreshing the page?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated this. Yeah to execute it instantly. It's to update data that's on a separate webpage and I want the script to run every time a user updates the data from the django admin pages.

Comment: Irmantas and Daniel, thanks for the info. I'll look into it. I honestly thought I could just sort of cheat and call the programme from the django project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If instantly: use javascript.

If by refreshing the page: just use requests and write your Python code as function in views.py

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have understood anything from the Django tutorial or documentation.

In Django, you access the server-side functionality via URLs, which are served by views. You don't reference a Python script directly in your template, you reference a URL which maps to a view, and your Python code goes in that view.

Quite apart from that, `onclick` is Javascript. You can't just reference a Python script, that makes no sense. You can write a Javascript function to call (via Ajax) a URL which does what you want, or more simply make it a link to that URL.